# How to pass login credentials to SSRS using Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

**Background**

I am currently working with an application that uses Web API. We he have implemented custom token based authentication. Our front end is primarily HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript. Although it is an MVC application we are only really using mvc for routing, because Web API handles much of everything else. We are evaluating SSRS as a possible reporting solution. We would like to keep our Website session-less as it currently stands.

**Question**

I have not been able to find a good implementation of SSRS with Web API. I basically want a simple Web API route that constructs the URL to the report server while passing parameters. I was able to find several resources on making a request and passing parameters via a URL. I am struggling with Authentication. How do I send the credentials to the report server via URL. In WebForms there is an interface called IReportServerCredentials that allows you to do this. Is there anything like this for WebAPI. Is there another solution for logging in via a URL? We want to either send the credentials directly with this call, or somehow tap into our current WebAPI Token Based Authentication.

On a side note if anyone knows a report viewer that will work on the client side I would appreciate it. Since our frontend is technically an MVC application I have been evaluating this one:

-https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer

That being said it is not ideal for what we are currently trying to accomplish.

Any help is much appreicated! I am very new to SSRS, so please forgive my ignorance towards the subject.